# Драйвер для HDD

Tags: c++, драйвер, hdd

Собственно то, что я сейчас понимаю:
Необходимо написать драйвер для HDD (Для устройства, а не файловой системе), т.к. из режима пользователя обратиться к нему нельзя. И следующим шагом зашифровать его, т.е. установить на него пароль. (Как дополнение: все это реализовать под Винду и на C++)

Следовательно, из выше сказанного, я не знаю как написать этот самый драйвер и после этого установить пароль. Именно во всем этом мне и нужна помощь.

P.S. Гугл мне в этом не помог.

Comment: Нагуглите готовый драйвер на C++ и прикрутите к нему свое шифрование - так будет проще

Comment: Драйвер пишется под определенную ОС, в текущем виде вопрос слишком общий. "установить пароль" - тоже слишком расплывчатое понятие.

Comment: Вам нужна отдельно документация на работу с SATA (или может у вас все еще IDE ?) и отдельно литература по разработке драйверов для той операционной системы для которой вы хотите его писать. И возможно, дополнительно, техническая документация на конкретный HDD от производителя, в случае если он может выполнять нестандартные функции и вы их хотите использовать

Comment: Возможно вам вполне хватило бы готовых решений (конечно, если вы не желаете просто обучиться писать драйверы), например есть TrueCrypt (читать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt и качать https://www.truecrypt71a.com/downloads/) - позволяет шифровать диск, также создавать на нём шифрованные файлы-контейнеры, используя пароль для расшифровки.

Comment: Кстати, т.к. TrueCrypt может шифровать целые диски, значит у них есть драйвер для шифрованного диска, потому вы можете у них в исходниках поучиться как его писать. Исходники тут https://github.com/AuditProject/truecrypt-verified-mirror

Comment: Определитесь, вы хотите написать драйвер для **устройства** или для **файловой системы**.

Comment: Для **устройства**

Comment: Спецификация этого устройства есть у вас?

Comment: Да, есть. (Seagate ST9120411ASG SATA Hard Drive)

Comment: Это модель, а не спецификация. Но раз говорите, что есть -- в чём проблема просто следовать ей?